# Box2d making a body follow the mouse accurately

Tags: c++, mathematics, physics, box2d

I am trying to make a box2d `b2Body` follow my mouse position. This is the code I am using at the moment but it is not performing very well:

```
deltaPos = mousePos - body->GetPosition();
deltaPos *= k;
body->ApplyForce(deltaPos, b2Vec2(0, 0));
```

I have tried playing with `k` but the body either lags too far behind the mouse or flies round and round the mouse like crazy. Should I be using an exponentiation there instead of multiplication? I am scared of applying too much force and breaking the sim (I suppose I could use a max).

Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Mouse Joint to "attach" the mouse to the body (see http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082974)

If that doesn't work well for whatever reason, the manual suggests using a kinematic body and adjusting its position manually(http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082973)